# How create json string from tidy data

Tags: r

Hi I have a set CSV files that I need to import into mongo DB.

my data is already tidy, I want to untidy it to create json object I can import.

For example:

```
client, receipt, total
1       101      $10
1       102      $11
2       201      $10
```

I woudl like to create list of json strings like:

```
list:
[1]
{  
   "client":1,
   "receipts":[  
      {  
         "receipt":101,
         "charge":10
      },
      {  
         "receipt":102,
         "charge":11
      }
   ]
}
[2]
{  
   "client":2,
   "receipts":[  
      {  
         "receipt":201,
         "charge":10
      }
   ]
}
```

This was supposed to be a simple problem but it looks that all google results are talking about getting json into a tidy data.frame instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
df<-read.table(header=T, text="client receipt charge
1       101      10
1       102      11
2       201      10")
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  nest(-client, .key = receipts) %>% 
  split(.$client) %>% 
  map(~toJSON(unbox(.x), pretty=TRUE)) 
# $`1`
# {
#     "client": 1,
#     "receipts": [
#       {
#         "receipt": 101,
#         "charge": 10
#       },
#       {
#         "receipt": 102,
#         "charge": 11
#       }
#     ]
#   } 
# 
# $`2`
# {
#     "client": 2,
#     "receipts": [
#       {
#         "receipt": 201,
#         "charge": 10
#       }
#     ]
#   }
```

Comment: Luke works like charm, thank you. I had a similar idea but you nailed it.